# Kivy android Greek Chars

Tags: android, python, oracle, kivy

I have a Kivy app with sqlite database
It works fine on Windows , but when I put it on android it craches
The problem is Greek characters.
I import data from an oracle database with NLS_CHARACTERSET

```
EL8MSWIN1253
```

What character set must I have to work in android?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Comment: Nowadays the default character set is `AL32UTF8`

Comment: You mean , I have to change the character set in Oracle or I have to convert string values in select statement?